# DjangoRestFramwork how to override ModelViewSet get method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, get

I have a model like this :

```py
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAccountAdminOrReadOnly]
```

How do I override the get method so when I hit `/api/accounts/8` I can add some code before returning the 8th account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelViewSet` have `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin`, which call when you hit `/api/accounts/8`.You can override `retrieve` method from it and do extra work.

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAccountAdminOrReadOnly]

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #todo anything
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the retrieve method of your ActionViewSet.

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwarge):
    account = self.get_object()
    # write your extra codes here
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance=account)
    return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    return Response(
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `retrieve` method.

`/api/accounts/8` is a detail api call. It uses the retrieve method.

So, If you look at the viewset code. we can find that.

```py
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet):
    """
    A viewset that provides default `create()`, `retrieve()`, `update()`,
    `partial_update()`, `destroy()` and `list()` actions.
    """
    pass
```

### solution

```py
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAccountAdminOrReadOnly]

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do your stuff - start
        ...
        # end
        return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

ref: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py